# Edits to Comment based help are not refreshed

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

** Update **

Turns out I'm just a moron. The same function was defined multiple times in the psm1 file, each with it's own copy of the help text. Deleting the extra definitions and editing the help text results in behavior as expected.

I have flagged this question for review and deletion by the moderators.

I have a psm1 module file and corresponding psd1 manifest.

```
$varTable = @{}
$varTable.Add('Key1','First Example Value')
$varTable.Add('Key2','Second Example Value')

function Test-Function{
    Write-Host "Hello World"
    <#
    .EXAMPLE
    Test-Function

    This Function simply prints Hello World.
    This is an extra line in this example text that I will delete later.
    #>
}

Export-ModuleMember -Variable "*"
```

One of my examples in the help comments has a line of text I would like to remove. My problem is that no matter what I do to edit the function's help text, it never actually changes when I load the module. The text remains the same.

If I change the $varTable to add a new key like:

```
$varTable.Add('NewKey','New Value')
```

Then when I reload the module, either through Import-Module ModuleName -force or by closing my session, or I've even tried restarting my computer, the $varTable changes as expected, but the extra line in the example text never goes away when I execute Get-Help Test-Function -Full.

I have confirmed that the edit is saved to disk by the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem $psHome\Modules\ModuleName\ModuleName.psm1 | %{Notepad.exe $_.FullName}
```

The text I see in notepad shows the text is gone and it also shows the edit to the $varTable, but the text never changes when I run Get-Help.

I've actually gone so far at this point as deleting all of the comment based help from all of my functions, restarting and reloading the module, and all of the comment based help still displays if I call Get-Help on one of my modules functions. Again though, each time I edit, if I change the name of a key in the $varTable or change the number of keys, or even if I add an entirely new variable, a simple Import-Module ModuleName -Force is enough to make the change in my session.

Is there some sort of cache I'm not clearing?

I have seen that there are similar questions to this one where the -force switch works, but I'm posting this as a new question because those questions are old and aren't solving my issue.

Thanks,
Bill

** Update **

I just deleted all of the functions from the psm1 so that all of the module did was assign one variable. Get-Command -Module ModuleName returned nothing, and trying to use Get-Help FunctionName returns an error that the help topic cannot be found.

I then add back the function definition with no comment based help at all, just the function code. When I run Get-Help FunctionName it returns the full help topic that isn't even there any more.

Comment: What if you change the version in the psd1?

Comment: @briantist I just generated a new manifest using New-ModuleManifest and incremented the version from 1.0 to 1.0.1 and then again to 2.0 and neither had any effect.

Comment: Did you reimport the module with `-Force` after that? FWIW, I have not had the problem you're describing in Powershell 3 or 4, but I wasn't really writing modules when I was using PS2 primarily.

Comment: I did. I'm getting a little crazy about it at this point so I did that. I closed all of my sessions and the ISE again and restarted again. All to no avail.

Comment: @Keith Hill's answer looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

Information about modules is cached.  You can refresh the cache like so:

```
Get-Module ModuleName -Refresh
```

BTW are you removing the module between changes e.g.:

```
Remove-Module ModuleName
Import-Module ModuleName
```

Comment: The PS 2.0 version of Get-Module does not have the -Refresh parameter. It only has -All -ListAvailable -Name and then the common parameters.

Comment: Ah bummer, and there's no chance you can upgrade to WMF3 given v2 is ~6 years old and V5 is in beta?  Not that I would want to pressure you into anything.  ;-)

Comment: I would love to. Problem is that I work with a lot of healthcare clients and most of them refuse to allow upgrades to platforms like that. If it doesn't come in Patch Tuesday they don't want it. So that's the environment I have to test for.

Comment: I just noticed your Remove-Module suggestion. Using Remove-Module at least gets Powershell to acknowledge that the help content is missing if I delete all of the help, which is a step in the right direction I guess. But when I add the corrected content back in, remove the module and then add it again, it goes back to displaying the old help content that isn't even in the file anymore.